# How to secure execution of the loaded class in Android?

Tags: android, classloader

I would like to load a class in Android app (Java). My concern is that a malicious class can be executed instead of the expected one. What tools can I use to prevent potential malicious actions like taking an advantage of granted permissions? Or stealing my app data?

I would like to know solutions regardless of the origin of the loaded class.

I've found SecurityManager, but it's disabled in Android and also will be deprecated in future.
Googling "sandboxing" results in many explanation of app sandboxing, but I would like to sandbox certain part of an app, for example a thread.

Comment: "My concern is that a malicious class can be executed instead of the expected one" -- how do you anticipate this happening?

Comment: Is that completely impossible? In my use case user Im compiling code from user and executing it inside my app. Perhaps it is very extreme case, but many static analysis tools are generating a warning if you use a class loader so there must be something dangerous in it in general?

Comment: "Is that completely impossible?" -- no, but your defenses would be tied to where and how you anticipate the malicious code getting into your app. "In my use case user Im compiling code from user and executing it inside my app" -- rather than asking a general question, you might ask a much more specific question: how to sandbox code where you are intentionally doing something insecure. "so there must be something dangerous in it in general?" -- using a `ClassLoader` is dangerous. Few developers do that, since the Play Store has policies against it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are an Android application developer you should not be investing effort here as JVM(ART or Dalvik) takes care of all security related to execution of loaded classes moreover I have never heard of any hack / expolit in Android that enables executing of code java that was not packaged with the APK.

**Note** JS code and its vulnerabilities are something completely different than running Java class in JVM.

If you are instead working on Android OEM platform / firmware code then you ca refer to Android guidelines on class loaders [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ClassLoader).

Comment: ok, so then why static analysis tools are generating a warning if you use a class loader?

Comment: @renc Can you edit the question with exact warnings that you are receiving??